# How Would You Print The "IF" Statement Multiple Times and Have it in Post Order

Tags: php

```
// These are my Variables
$a = "a";
$b = "b";
$c = "c";

//My Post Form Data
$post = $_POST['name'];

//My Statements
if (isset($_POST['name']) && preg_match("/\b($a)\b/", $post )) {
    echo '64';
}
if (isset($_POST['name']) && preg_match("/\b($b)\b/", $post )) {
    echo '67';
}
if (isset($_POST['name']) && preg_match("/\b($c)\b/", $post )) {
    echo '66';
}
```

The problem is I want `abc` to be in `form order` and to print more then once. So if I enter `cba` I want it to print `666764`.

If I send my form input as `cbaa` I want my input to be `66676464`. currently it would be posting as this `646766`!

edit: muhammads worked!

Comment: Use `str_replace(['a','b','c'], [64,67,66], $str)` instead

Comment: Yours worked! I tip my hat to you, in fact it shortened the code a lot. Thankyou.

Comment: Never mind, it doesn't allow me to one letter now.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/jSnrL ?

Comment: I'm an idiot. Yes it works lol. thanks mate.

Comment: `$post = $_POST['name'];

$print = str_replace(['a','b','c'], [64,67,66], $post);

echo $print;`

Comment: You said *it doesn't allow me to one letter now*

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate from string

```
$statements = [
    'a' = 64, 
    'b' = 67, 
    'c' = 66
];

$input = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null;
$output = null;

for($x = 0; $x < strlen($input); $x++) {
    $letter = strtolower($input[$x]);

    if(!isset($statements[$letter])) {
        continue;
    }

    // Do something if 'a', 'b', 'c'
    // if($letter == 'a') etc ..

    $output .= "" . $statements[$letter];
}

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Mohammad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5104748/mohammad)'s comment is probably the most concise answer for this problem, all credit goes to him.

Using [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-replace.php) function makes it a one liner:

```
$str = 'cbaa';
$res = str_replace(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['65', '66', '67'], $str);
echo $res;
// prints 67666565 as expected
```